# Use winapi to generate http proxy ntlm messages

Tags: c++, c, winapi, boost-asio

I need to enable ntlm http proxy authentication for my boost::asio based network client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd925287(v=office.12).aspx. So i want to stay with boost and won't use other libraries like cUrl etc. I wonder is there any winapi functions to generate ntlm http proxy messages from current user credentials or do i have to manually parse corresponding secure registry branches to get ntlm hashes and compose them like CNTLM proxy do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to implement it yes.

If I were you I'd just find an open source implementation (suitably licensed).  CNTLM might have that (?).

As far as I remember, libcurl supports NTLM proxies, so you might simply use that.

There are multiple projects that bridge libcurl to Boost Asio.